# гугл таблица почему-то не всегда может применить функцию ЧАС() к высчитанному времени

Tags: функции, excel, google-spreadsheet

В столбце F формула скопирована во все ячейки. Однако в строке 3 результат высчитывается, а два других примера - нет.
Не понимаю, в чём может быть ошибка.

P.S.:
Все данные вводятся в одинаковом временном формате.
Если в столбец F ввести время вручную, всё работает.
Если время в столбце F меняет формат, то я не знаю, как это выяснить, или, тем более, исправить(

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А по какой формуле получено 10:05 в D4? Возможно, там на самом деле -13:55, просто таблица отображает это значение иначе?

Comment: *данные... в одинаковом временном формате. Если в столбец F ввести время вручную, всё работает* - очень похоже, что путаете **формат данных** и **формат ячейки**. Если в ячейку с форматом времени внести текстовые данные, похожие на время, будет точно такая же ситуация, как Вы описали

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте в колонке D формулу такого вида

```
=C2-B2+(B2>C2)
```

Добавка `+(B2>C2)` будет иметь значение 0 в случае, если время начала периода и время окончания находятся в одном дне. Если период проходит через полночь, то эта добавка получит значение 1 (или 24 часа).

Это не надёжный приём! Если работа начата, например, в 18:00, а закончена в 18:15 на следующий день, то формула вернёт не 24:15, а только пятнадцать минут.

Чтобы избежать таких ошибок, лучше не разделять дату и время по отдельным ячейкам (как это было сделано в таблице на скриншоте). Если бы в ячейках находились значения вида `24.11.2021 15:00` и `25.11.2021 1:05`, то обычное вычитание без всяких "добавок" возвращало бы правильный результат `10:05:00`

Кроме того, совсем не обязательно использовать `ЧАС()` и `МИНУТЫ()`, чтобы получить время в виде десятичного числа - просто умножьте время на 24 (`=F2*24`) и отформатируйте как число.

Comment: время*24 покажет не только часы, но и дробную часть - минуты и секунды. Если уж заменять `ЧАС` на *24, то нужно отрезать лишнее (функция `ЦЕЛОЕ`)

Comment: @vikttur У него там ещё и МИНУТЫ()/60 - то есть дробная часть тоже нужна.

Comment: *и отформатируйте как число* Если же и `ЧАС`и `МИНУТЫ` одним значением, то тоже замена не всегда корректна. 1/60 часа и 1/100 десятичного значения не совпадают